# How could I transform the numpy array to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to analyze using python, I wonder how can I transform the format of the left table to the right one. My initial thought is to create a nested for loop.

[The desired table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1hq.png)
First, I find read the required csv file.

[Imported csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMu7.png)

Then, I count the number of countries in the Column 'country' and the number of the new column names list.

```
`countries = len(test['country'])`
`columns = len(['Year', 'Values'])`
```

After that, I should go for the nested for loop, however, I have no idea on writing the code.What I have come up was as follows:

```
`for i in countries:`
  `for j in columns:`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) here:

```
In [3575]: df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Afghanistan', 'Albania'], '1970':[1.36, 6.1], '1971':[1.39, 6.22], '1972':[1.43, 6.34]})

In [3576]: df
Out[3576]: 
       country  1970  1971  1972
0  Afghanistan  1.36  1.39  1.43
1      Albania  6.10  6.22  6.34

In [3609]: df = df.melt('country', var_name='Year', value_name='Values').sort_values('country')

In [3610]: df
Out[3610]: 
       country  Year  Values
0  Afghanistan  1970    1.36
2  Afghanistan  1971    1.39
4  Afghanistan  1972    1.43
1      Albania  1970    6.10
3      Albania  1971    6.22
5      Albania  1972    6.34
```

Comment: @CheTou Please check my answer. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: not sure that this is what he wanted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1hq.png

Comment: @dallonsi My output matches exactly the output pasted by OP in the image. What am I missing here?

Comment: oh right my mistake ! He starts with this table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMu7.png I thought he wanted to go from the right table to the left table on this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1hq.png .... !!

Comment: @Mayank Porwal Yes, this is what I want. And I have asked my friend the same question and he gave me another approach to get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want to do, but:

- If you want to transform a column in a numpy array, you can use the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [1,2,3], "bar": [10,20,30]})
print(df)

foo_array = np.array(df["foo"])
print(foo_array)
```

and then iterate on `foo_array`

- You can also loop on your data frame using :

```py
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

But it's not recommended since you can often use built in pandas function to do the same job.

- your data frame is also an iterable object which only contains the columns names:

```py
for d in df:
    print(d)

# output:
# foo
# bar
```

Comment: I would like to change the columns' name in the original table to values in the new columns, just like this image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1hq.png